# HP Laptop not charging when working, doesn't start without battery - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-supply, battery, power

I have a HP laptop and yesterday I accidentally hit the laptop on the table. It was fine but when I charged it, it didn't charge at all. When it had 60% remains, the charging indicator showed white- fully charged. I close the lip to make it sleep and the indicator changed to red- charging. When I opened it, it turned back to white.

---

I checked the tutorials online, I uninstall battery AC options in device manager and restarted it twice and it didn't work. Also, when I shut down the computer, I toke off the battery but with the AC charger charging, I could not boot the computer.

---

I tried to posit the charger inside the DC power jack in an angle and length and sustained in a few seconds then it's charging! I pushed it into the deepest and it's still charging even it's working. But here is the problem, when I close the lid, and reopen it, it doesn't charge anymore. I have to do it again and it's taking me a long time to do once. Here are my questions,

1. Why it's happening?
2. How can I solve this?
3. Do I need to replace anything?

Thank you so much for help!

Comment: It appears you have damaged the power socket on the laptop. You should take it to a computer repair shop.